# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MessageBox

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm, masm32

I am trying to create a helloworld program using only masm and not masm32 libs. Here is the code snippet:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

extrn MessageBox : PROC
extrn ExitProcess : PROC

.data
        HelloWorld db "Hello There!", 0

.code
start:

        lea eax, HelloWorld
        mov ebx, 0
        push ebx
        push eax
        push eax
        push ebx
        call MessageBox
        push ebx
        call ExitProcess

end start
```

I am able to assemble this using masm:

```
c:\masm32\code>ml /c /coff demo.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 9.00.21022.08
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: demo.asm
```

However, I am unable to link it:

```
c:\masm32\code>link /subsystem:windows /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:user
32.lib demo.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.21022.08
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

demo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MessageBox
demo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ExitProcess
demo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I am including the libs during linking, so not sure why it still says unresolved symbols?

UPDATE:

```
c:\masm32\code>link /subsystem:windows /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:user
32.lib demo.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.21022.08
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

demo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MessageBox@16
demo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

**UPDATE 2: Final working code!**

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

extrn MessageBoxA@16 : PROC
extrn ExitProcess@4 : PROC

.data
        HelloWorld db "Hello There!", 0

.code
start:

        lea eax, HelloWorld
        mov ebx, 0
        push ebx
        push eax
        push eax
        push ebx
        call MessageBoxA@16
        push ebx
        call ExitProcess@4

end start
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct function names are `MessageBoxA@16` and `ExitProcess@4`.

Almost all Win32 API functions are stdcall, so [their names are decorated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) with an `@` sign, followed by the number of bytes taken up by their parameters.

Additionally, when a Win32 function takes a string, there are two variants: one that takes an ANSI string (name ends in `A`) and one that takes a Unicode string (name ends in `W`). You're supplying an ANSI string, so you want the `A` version.

When you're not programming in assembly the compiler takes care of these points for you.

Comment: Thanks! This resolved one of the link errors but not the other.. see update

Comment: Awesome! worked perfectly now. I feel like such a n00b - can you suggest any docs / books where I can pick all this stuff up from? MSDN is too daunting to explore when you are a novice.

Comment: You may also want to refer Iczelion's Win32 ASM tutorials: http://win32assembly.online.fr/

Comment: I like Randall Hyde's stufF: http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/Win32Asm/index.html. He uses HLA, which is effectively a set of macros on top of raw MASM, but the principles are the same.

Comment: BTW, these are not noobie questions: with assembly, you're having to deal with a lot of annoying details that higher-level tools normally handle.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! :) You are a life saver for me today.

Comment: @Jumbo, I think asking a new question for docs / books for Assembly would be very valid :)

Comment: you can use invoke to avoid push

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this before `.data` segment:

```
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
```