# Generating .OBJs with NASM and linking with LINK.EXE successfully generates a .exe but the Program hangs, Why?

Tags: assembly

I use NASM as an Assembler, I'm trying to learn Assembly Language after C++, and I'm facing too much problems like after generating .OBJ with the Command `nasm -f win32 c:\asm\assembly.asm` this generates a assembly.obj file, and after using a command in CMD `link c:\asm\assembly.obj /OUT:c:\asm\assembly.exe /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /ENTRY:start` this generates a assembly.exe file.

But if I try to open it, Windows displays a box saying "The Program has stopped working" Whats it?? I'm very confused, and I'm aware of the IDEs in the Internet, but don't want to use any of them, I like the command prompt window, but never used it for linking any of my Applications(c++), And this is the Code copied from [TutorialsPoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_basic_syntax.htm):

NOTE*: All Comments are Orignal as on the TutorialsPoint's Website, it is'nt mine...

```
section .text
    global _start   ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start:             ;tells linker entry point
    mov edx,len     ;message length
    mov ecx,msg     ;message to write
    mov ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
    
    mov eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg              ;length of our dear string
```

I tried changing _start to `_WinMain@16` as on a Website(Windows Programs uses _WinMain instead _start on linux) but it gives Linker error:Unresolved Externals, But this code Assembled and linked fine, the Only problem i faced is that the Applications get hanged or they Stoped working.

Thanx in Advance!!

Comment: The code you're assembling is written for an x86 Linux system. That's not going to work in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes because you're trying to run assembly made for Linux on Windows. Here your code is trying to call some of the Linux kernel's syscalls to write a Hello World and exit, but this can't work on Windows. Assembly is rarely multi-platform.

As a rule of thumb, if you see `int 0x80` chances are that this code will not work on Windows.

Instead on Windows you can try calling the MessageBox function in kernel32.dll for example to display your HelloWorld, see [this post if you need some help with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123013/helloworld-in-win32-assembly).